# Cache problems with menu Joomla

Tags: php, caching, joomla, joomla1.6

I have a problem in Joomla 1.6.

I have a menu with 5 menu items and if I log in I should be able to see 2 more. This is practicly working, but if I'm logging in while I'm on the home page (or any other page), the 2 menu items doesn't appear until I've clicked one of the other menu items, which I think might be because of some cache setting somewhere??

Anyone know where in Joomla I can set such settings?

I've also set the global cache setting in Joomla to "OFF" and it appears in both Firefox and IE.

Comment: have you checked if those menus can be seen on the *root* while logged? (or if they have the permissions to be viewed?)

Comment: Yep, they have the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try changine the following settings in your Menu and Module Managers:

```
Menu Manager: Menu Items -> [Your Menu] -> [Your Special Menu Items]
 - Access: Registered

Module Manager: Module Menu -> Basic Options :
- End Level : All
- Show Submenu Items: Yes

Module Manager: Module Menu -> Advanced Options :
- Caching: No caching

Module Manager: Module Menu -> Menu Assignment:
- Module Assignment: On All Pages

Module Manager: Module Menu -> Details: 
- Access: Registered
```

You probably missed one of those